# VBA rs.filter Mysql date between

Tags: mysql, vba, filter, recordset

Currently, I'm accessing a record set

```
tmpQuery = SELECT * FROM someImportantTable 
WHERE(name like '% {Some Value}  %') 
AND date_field BETWEEN '{Some Value}' AND '{Some Value}';
```

then doing

```
set tmpRS = someDatabase.execute(tmpQuery)
```

I am trying to reduce the amount of opening repeat connection to this table, so I want to do a `rs.filter` instead.

However, I can't seem to master the syntax

I assumed it something like this:

`rs.filter =  [name] LIKE '%%' AND [date_field] >= #01/04/2016# AND [date_field] <= #30/04/2016#`

or

`rs.filter =  [name] LIKE '%%' AND [date_field] >= #2016-04-01# AND [date_field] <= #2016-04-30#`

But it keeps giving me an error when it performed I get an error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
rs.filter = "[date_field] >= #04/01/2016# AND [date_field] <= #04/30/2016#"
```

Comment: that worked however I need to add.

"[name] LIKE '%%' AND" as well

Comment: UPDATE: the reason it wasn't working is I need to add if statment checking if the like %% will be empty or not.